# how can a beginner implementing getaddress.io API using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen posts relating to this API but there is no post that actually helps a beginner implement this. I have been able to get the json data what I anm struggling with is getting the data into the form as shown on the demo of the getaddress.io web page. Can someone please help me, the dropdown seems to be hidden and only appears when the search button if invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure JQuery is referenced.

Here is an online example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YBEOxSoeQxDCeRC1yHwh?p=preview

```js
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress({
    api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY', 
    output_fields:{
        line_1: '#line1',
        line_2: '#line2',
        line_3: '#line3',
        post_town: '#town',
        postcode: '#postcode'
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://getaddress.io/js/jquery.getAddress-2.0.8.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <form>
      
      <!-- Postcode field -->
<div id="postcode_lookup"></div>  

<!-- Add to your existing form -->
<label>First Address Line</label>
<input id="line1" type="text"> 

<label>Second Address Line</label>
<input id="line2" type="text">   

<label>Third Address Line</label>
<input id="line3" type="text">  

<label>Town</label>
<input id="town" type="text">

<label>Postcode</label>
<input id="postcode" type="text">
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>

</html>
```